# Saving webpart in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have a complex form in my webpart. It has JS, JQuery, Bootstrap and form is too complex. I have deployed the form in farm solutions. It works fine.
Then I tried to deploy it to sharepoint online. It has been done. After I have inserted webpart and try to save page shows message "Saving", and it never ends.
I tried several times and failed.

How to overcome this issue?
Is there any shortcut to save and close rather than waiting?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the browser's developer tools to see what's going on. Could be a JavaScript error that causes the page to hang or that a ressource isn't being properly loaded. Also run Fiddler to see what goes over the wire and the HTTP status codes.

You can't assume that something that previously worked in a farm solution (a full-trust environment) will just work in SharePoint Online (low-trust environment). That's highly unlikely to be the case.

Comment: True. But there is no errors in browser's developer tools.